# Lewis acidity order of Aluminum Halides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

There is a similar question already on StackExchange which was not satisfactorily answered. So I am asking it again. I am unable to find this information in any book.

Link to the other question:
[Acidity of aluminium trihalides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80263/acidity-of-aluminium-trihalides&ved=2ahUKEwi15tukyZPqAhVFWX0KHYddDnkQjjgwDXoECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2MWf1lYBhA5YAy40gASS9U)

Comment: What question do you refer to? What is unsatisfactory about the existing answer? Why the name of the scientist isn't capitalized, but the name of a chemical compound is? Also, please familiarize yourself with [the homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448).

Comment: I have provided the link @adnselisk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Acidity of aluminium trihalides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80263/acidity-of-aluminium-trihalides)

Comment: I just wanted an answer and so asked it again...as no one answered the previous one properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Ref.1: The order of Lewis acidity of gaseous halides of aluminum is established to be $\ce{AlF3(g) < AlCl3(g) < AlBr3(g) \approx AlI3(g)}$. The order of Lewis acidity of molecular and solid group 13 halides is $\ce{AlX3(g) > GaX3(g) > InX3(g)}$ (where $\ce{X = F, Cl, Br, I}$).

**References:**

1. Thoralf Krahl, Erhard Kemnitz, “The very strong solid Lewis acids aluminium chlorofluoride (ACF) and bromofluoride (ABF)—Synthesis, structure, and Lewis acidity,” *Journal of Fluorine Chemistry* **2006**, *127(6)*, 663-678 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfluchem.2006.02.015).

Comment: Does the solid state also have the same order?

Comment: Can't say without any data. Keep in mind that at solid state, these halides tend to make dimers, trimers, etc., thus different than gaseous phase.

Comment: Ok....does the same order apply for the catalytic action during Friedel Crafts reaction?

Comment: Should be. But most common one is $\ce{AlCl3}$ due to its covalent nature in non-polar solvents.